# the sum of all numbers below N that contain the digit 7

Tags: python

Can you please help me to find the issue in my code?
The exercise is; Write a program to input number N in range of [1-1000] and print the sum of all numbers below N that contain the digit 7. Print an error message if the user inserts an out of range number and ask to insert again.

```
var = 1
while var == 1:
    n=int(input("Enter the Number in range [1,1000]:"))
    while n in range(0,1001):
        k = 0
        i=0
        m=0
        s=0
        e=0
        f=0
        g=0
        if n in range(100,1001):
            for c in range(100,n+1):
                if c%10 == 7:
                    i += c
                if (c//10)%10 == 7:
                    c%10 != 7
                    s += c
                if c//100 == 7:
                    (c//10)%10 != 7
                    c%10 != 7
                    e += c
            print(1188 + i + s + e)
        if n in range(0,100):
            for b in range(1,n+1):
                if b%10 == 7:
                    f += b
                if b//10 == 7:
                    g += b
            if b >= 77:
               g=g-77
            print(f+g)
        break
    else:
        print("n is not in the range")
```

It counts the sum in range (170,180) by adding always 170 and not only in this range.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There's a lot going on there. It might be easier to check if `"7"` is in `str(n)`, then add all the numbers that pass that test. Less code will be easier to debug... or avoid bugs in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

In `while` block, we are testing if `n` is valid or not. After `while` block there is a list comprehension.

```
contains_seven = [x for x in range(0,n+1) if '7' in str(x)]
```

We are taking every number in range 0 to n+1  which has '7' in it.
After that, we are summing them via `sum()` function and print it. Full implementation is:

```
while True:
    n = int(input("input n: "))
    if (n>0 and n<=1000):
        break    
    print("n is not in the range")

contains_seven = [x for x in range(0,n+1) if '7' in str(x)]
a = sum(contains_seven)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can convert our number to a `str()` and then to a `list()`.
After that we from, for example, `456` get `['4', '5', '6']`.
And now we can easily check if `7` is in our number. PROFIT!

Then we take our list with numbers which contain 7 to *args in `sum()` and get final result! Uhhuuuu! Yeah

```py
N = int(input("Write number: "))

while (N < 1) or (N > 1000):
    N = int(input("Write number again: "))

all_numbers_with_seven = [n for n in range(1, N) if '7' in list(str(n))]

print(sum(all_numbers_with_seven))
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain your answer?

Comment: You need to explain your answer in order to answer a question. Read [how to answer good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). I have downvoted you because of this 'Nice code doesn't need to be explaned'.

Comment: @Marceline Actually that link says, `"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."` *not* `"Expect to get downvoted if you do not provide a full explanation, especially if you a new contributor and this is your first time."`

Comment: Brevity is not posting only code. I think the Op is beginner and need full explanation in order to understand so answers need to be expositional.